# Windows 7 there are no logon servers available to service the logon request subdomain

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, domain

I've read other solutions, but my problem is slighlty different.
Problem occurs in domain environment. We work in a subdomain, but we also have some employees coming with notebooks registered in top level domain.
Our internall policy enforces them to logon their laptops with our special guest users accounts firstly, then they have access to our citrix web interface.
This was working untill Windows 7 appeard (on Xp we had no problems at all). When we try to logon with such a user (of course using convention domain\user, but also fqdn\user), we get after a while error message saying:

"There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request"

We played a bit with network settings, like adding dns suffixes for all subdomains, but, without any result. It looks like system has no problem with resolving names of our domain controllers. There are no connectivity problems. Moreover, there are no coresponding events in event log (system, app, security), like wouldn't anything happened.
At the same time, they are able to logon with their originall main-domain users without any problem (however now i think that this might be also a false assumption, because they have cached credentials already)

Just a thing to add - trusts are set bi-directional. Normally, our users are able to logon on top level domain servers. So this shouldn't be releated to trusts.

Any ideas?

Comment: The DNS Servers that are handed out via DHCP, do they resolve your domain name?

Comment: Yeah, i suppose, we expose via DHCP exactly the same DNS Servers as we use internally in subdomain. They also serve as domain controllers. However i would need to test in on pc registered in top level domain. We are going to prepare a test Windows 7 virtual machine and ask our colleagues to join it to the top level domain.

Comment: By default an unqualified username logon will go to the domain the OS belongs to. Are they specifying a logon username of user@subdomain.com or subdomain\user? Which domain do the problem laptops actually belong to? Which domain's DNS servers are assigned via DHCP? Is there a proper DNS delegation from Top DNS to Sub DNS? Can NON laptop users logon to the subdomain? Which dom do NON laptops do non laptop belong to? Do the laptops have a valid IP for your network and not an APIPA 169 address?

Comment: They are specifying subdomain\user. Laptops belong to the top domain in the forest. They are receiving adresses of our DNSs from our DHCP Server. There is no difference between laptop and non laptop users - we have not tested other users on those laptops. Laptops have 100% valid IP from DHCP, moreover, we assign fixed ip adresses in DHCP for every single mobile user (security reasons), and this works fine.

Comment: So the problem with laptops and desktops is largely the same with slight differences. (A) No problems logging into TOP domain (they all belong to TOP domain) (B) have problems logging to SUB domain but (C) laptop logins always fail flat out while (D) desktop logins fail but logon proceeds because of cached credentials? Are there any member machines belonging to the SUB domain and do they have any login issues? Does running DCDIAG on any of the DCs' report any issues?

Comment: A) - Yes, but they logon first on they notebooks in the top domain, while they are in the main location, then they come to us, and they logon with the same credentials, but within our site (with our IP Adress, DNSes). This (domain logon) may work, but as their credentials are already cached, as i undestand, this may be also a false assumption. D) might be true, but this is not yet correctly tested (hope to do this today). There are no machines with login issues as far as we know, despite of those "foreign" notebooks. Dcdiag reports only systemlog failure on one dc, but this is unrelated error.